# Gmap missing XMLHttpRequest header

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony framework to develop web site. Symfony recognize ajax call by  **XMLHttpRequest header**.

I have integrated Gmap on my page. Gmap making ajax request without XMLHttpRequest header.So symfony doesn't recognize ajax request.

Normal jquery ajax call have this header.

```
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

But Gmap doesn't add this.

```
GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var xml = GXml.parse(data); 
  ... 
}
```

The **GDownloadUrl** makes this ajax call. How can i add this header with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing **GDownloadUrl** function by **jquery.get** function.

```
jQuery.get('searchUrl',function(data) {
  var xml = GXml.parse(data); 
  ... 
}
```

This function attaches **XMLHttpRequest header**